# Async signal safety of C++ atomic type constructors

Tags: c++

I'm writing an application that requires a significant portion of the code to be async signal safe because I'm mixing threads and the fork system call. Are constructors for C++ atomic types guaranteed to be async signal safe?

Comment: `std::atomic` is a template, which atomic types do you mean? Which constructors? You can't assume much about `std::atomic<SomeArbitraryClass>` but `std::atomic<int>` doesn't do anything in its default constructor at all.

Comment: Ok thanks. That answers my question. I'm a C++ newbie coming from Java and C.

Comment: If you're accessing a value that is possibly uninitialized, it's typically UB even if you're not doing it from a signal handler.